# keras RNN 3d tensor input and 2d tensor output: Error when checking model target

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to use LSTM to model multi-sample time series data. My input data has shape (100, 93, 6) - 100 independent time series (from the same/similar process), 93 time steps, 6 dimensions at each observation. Output shape is (100, 93) - one bool output per time step for each independent time series. (This is a small sample of real data, of course). However, I can't figure out how to construct such a Network in Keras:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, core, Activation, Dense
import numpy as np

data = np.load('sample.npz')
X = data['x']
y = data['y']
print('X shape: ',X.shape)
print('{} samples, {} time steps, {} observations at each time step, per sample\n'.format(*X.shape))

print('y shape: ',y.shape)
print('{} samples, {} time steps, boolean outcome per observation\n'.format(*y.shape))

print(X[0][2], X[0][55])
print(y[0][2], y[0][92])
```

> X shape:  (100, 93, 6) 100 samples, 93 time steps, 6 observations at
>   each time step, per sample
>
> y shape:  (100, 93) 100 samples, 93 time steps, boolean outcome per
>   observation
>
> [  1.80000000e+01   1.56000000e+05   2.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+04
>      3.00000000e+00   5.94000000e+04] [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
>
> 1.0 0.0

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=4, input_shape=(93, 6), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, verbose=2)
```

> Exception: Error when checking model target: expected dense_2 to have
>   shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (100, 93)

I believe Keras assumes that I have one output (Y) per timeseries, while I have one output per time step per time series. How do I make it work in Keras?

Answer (score 4):

I was missing `TimeDistributed` Layer..
This works:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=4, input_shape=(93, 6), return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: my Xtrian size [800, 14, 1000] and Ypredict size [800, 14, 1000] and I found TimeDistributed is work for me. Thanks so much!